# can windows programs running on windows XP or 7 run on windows 2012 r2?

Tags: windows, compatibility

I am managing a "legacy" environment,owned by retired developers.
A have many Windows Forms Silverlight applications built with VS 2010,2012,2013 running on windows xp and windows 7.

We are moving to a new hardware/software environment running windows 2012 R2,so 
I was asked if these older applications can run on ws2012r2.

My understanding is that these applications should work;what is the best approch to answer this problem?
Thank you

Comment: The best? Test them on a real system obviously.

Comment: If the applications are entirely bug-free, they will probably work the same on 2012 R2 as they did on XP/Windows 7.  However, very few applications are *entirely* bug free.  The only way to be sure there isn't an undiscovered bug that will cause problems is to test the software on the version of Windows you're intending to use.